# Combinatorics to calculate hamming distance

Tags: combinatorics

We have a string S of length L  comprising of alphabets between a to z. We write all strings of length L formed by taking just alphabets a and b. If L=3 we can form aaa aba bba etc. If L is 2 we can form ab ba bb and aa .Is there any combinatorics method to find all strings such that hamming distance between S and all letters formed of length L by using a and b is K where k is less than L.              Hamming distance is the number of positions at which characters are different in two strings. If string A is AAB and string B is AAC then hamming distance between string A and B  is 1.
For clarity of question, We form all possible  new strings comprising of letter a and b and of length L and out of those strings we choose the ones whose hamming distance with string S is K. If L=5 then there are 2^5 possible strings and out of those we need to check if hamming distance between S and them is equal to k.

let the string be abc.

if we look at all posiible strings of lenth 3 formed by just a nd b are

strings      >   hamming distance

aba-   1

aab    2

baa   3

bba   2

bab   3

bbb   2

aaa   2

abb   1

so ans is 4 if k=2 ,ans is 2 if k=3.

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question twice (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731654/hamming-distance-using-combinatorics). This version is better-phrased, but as you know, you can edit questions rather than just creating new versions.

Answer (score 1):

Let the string $S$ have $m$ letters that are either 'a' or 'b' and $n$ that aren't. If $n\gt k$, there are no admissible strings, since the Hamming distance is at least $n$. If $n\le k$, we can choose any $k-n$ of the $m$ letters to flip from 'a' to 'b' or vice versa, and for the $n$ letters that aren't 'a' or 'b' we can freely choose either 'a' or 'b'. Thus there are

$$
2^n\binom m{k-n}
$$

such strings.

Comment: We form all possible  new strings comprising of letter a and b and of length L and out of those strings we choose the ones whose hamming distance with string S is K. If L=5 then there are 2^5 possible strings and out of those we need to check if hamming distance between S and them is equal to k.

Comment: @satya: OK, I'd misunderstood -- I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: it is still not correct ,look at the example i gave in question.

Comment: @satya: You miscounted in the example. Two strings that begin with 'a' are listed with Hamming distance $3$ despite coinciding with the given string on the intial 'a'. Also, the last string `abb` has Hamming distance $1$ from `abc`, not $2$.

Comment: i corrected it now so will your formula work correctly here?

Comment: @satya: You tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38068/discussion-between-satya-and-joriki).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the mathematical formula but this simple DP recurrence will do the trick for you.

dp[i][j] == number of prefixes of length i have hamming distance of j

1)  if the last character we add is same as given string , then 
    dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j]

2)  if the last character we added is not similar to given string then
    dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j-1]*(A-1) where A is the number of possible
    characters allowed.

Therefore dp[i][j]  = dp[i-1][j-1]*(A-1) + dp[i-1][j] .

Therefore final answer will be sum of dp[n][0] + dp[n][1] +.....+ dp[n][k]

Hope this resolves your query :)

```
Here is the code - snippet `

 dp[0][0] = 1 ;
   dp[0][1] =  A   - 1 ;

  for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
   {
   for( int j= 0 ; j < n ; j ++ )
      {

        if(  i-1 >= 0 && j-1>=0)
         dp[i][j]+=dp[i-1][j-1]*(A - 1);

        if(  i-1 >= 0 && j>=0)
            dp[i][j]+=dp[i-1][j];

       }

     }
```